# Textview text color not changing on click

Tags: android, textview, tableview, textcolor

I have an activity in which I have created a table dynamically. The table is populated from a SQLite database. Onclick the table header the table is getting sorted accordingly.

Everything is working fine, now my requirement is to change the text color of the table header textview when it is clicked. The text color is not getting changed.

This is the a **method which is populating the table**:

```
//Time ascending method
    public void populateTableTimeAscending()
    {
        getTimeNameTimeAsc();
        getStudentNameTimeAsc();
        follow_up_table.removeAllViews();
        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow followup_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        followup_tr_head.setId(10);
        followup_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        followup_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView time_name_title = new TextView(this);
        time_name_title.setId(20);
        time_name_title.setText("Time");
        time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        time_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(time_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        time_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        TextView student_name_title = new TextView(this);
        student_name_title.setId(20);
        student_name_title.setText("Student Name");
        student_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        student_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(student_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        student_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableTimeDescending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------

        student_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableNameAscending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------


        follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //--------------- Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        Iterator itr = time_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        Iterator itr2 = student_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            while(itr2.hasNext())
            {

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------
                followup_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                followup_tr_data.setId(10);
                followup_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                followup_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                final TextView timeNameText = new TextView(this);
                timeNameText.setId(20);
                timeNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr.next().toString()));
                timeNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                timeNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                timeNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(timeNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                final TextView StudentNameText = new TextView(this);
                StudentNameText.setId(20);
                StudentNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr2.next().toString()));
                StudentNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                StudentNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                StudentNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(StudentNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------

            }

        }
    }
```

Inside **time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()** I have tried to change the text color which did not happen.

**----------------Edit full code----------------------------------**

```
public class TableActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout follow_up_table;
    TableRow followup_tr_data;

    List<String> time_name_list_time_asc;
    List<String> student_name_list_time_asc;

    List<String> time_name_list_time_dsc;
    List<String> student_name_list_time_dsc;

    List<String> time_name_list_studname_asc;
    List<String> student_name_studname_asc;

    List<String> time_name_list_studname_dsc;
    List<String> student_name_list_studname_dsc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

        follow_up_table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.follow_up_table);



        //getTime();

        // database handler

        deleteRows(); 

        insertData("Morning", "2013-04-23 10:00:00", "Suresh Kumar");
        insertData("Morning", "2013-04-23 11:30:00", "Pravat Das");
        insertData("Evening", "2013-04-23 16:16:00", "Namita Roy");
        insertData("Evening", "2013-04-23 17:30:00", "Rakesh Mitra");
        insertData("After noon", "2013-04-23 14:27:00", "Anil Sarma");


        //       getTimeNameTimeAsc();
        //       getStudentNameTimeAsc();
        //       getTimeNameTimeDsc();
        //       getStudentNameTimeDsc();
        //       getTimeNameSyudentAsc();
        //       getStudentNameStudentAsc();
        //       getTimeNameStudentDsc();
        //       getStudentNameStudentDsc();



        populateTableTimeAscending();
    }

    //==================================================================================//  
    //=============Functions for Table View=====================================================//
    //==================================================================================//  

    //Time ascending method
    public void populateTableTimeAscending()
    {
        getTimeNameTimeAsc();
        getStudentNameTimeAsc();
        follow_up_table.removeAllViews();
        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow followup_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        followup_tr_head.setId(10);
        followup_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        followup_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        final TextView time_name_title = new TextView(this);
        time_name_title.setId(20);
        time_name_title.setText("Time");
        time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        time_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(time_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        time_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        TextView student_name_title = new TextView(this);
        student_name_title.setId(20);
        student_name_title.setText("Student Name");
        student_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        student_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(student_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        student_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableTimeDescending();



            }
        });
        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------

        student_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableNameAscending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------


        follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //--------------- Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        Iterator itr = time_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        Iterator itr2 = student_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            while(itr2.hasNext())
            {

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------
                followup_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                followup_tr_data.setId(10);
                followup_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                followup_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                final TextView timeNameText = new TextView(this);
                timeNameText.setId(20);
                timeNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr.next().toString()));
                timeNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                timeNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                timeNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(timeNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                final TextView StudentNameText = new TextView(this);
                StudentNameText.setId(20);
                StudentNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr2.next().toString()));
                StudentNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                StudentNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                StudentNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(StudentNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------

            }

        }
    }




    //Time descending method
    public void populateTableTimeDescending()
    {
        getTimeNameTimeDsc();
        getStudentNameTimeDsc();
        follow_up_table.removeAllViews();

        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow followup_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        followup_tr_head.setId(10);
        followup_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        followup_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView time_name_title = new TextView(this);
        time_name_title.setId(20);
        time_name_title.setText("Time");
        time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        time_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(time_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        time_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        TextView student_name_title = new TextView(this);
        student_name_title.setId(20);
        student_name_title.setText("Student Name");
        student_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        student_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(student_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        student_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        //----------------------On click setOnClickListener---------------------------------------

        time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                populateTableTimeAscending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click setOnClickListener---------------------------------------

        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------

                student_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //makeAToast("Hello!");
                        populateTableNameAscending();

                    }
                });
                //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------


        follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //--------------- Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        Iterator itr = time_name_list_time_dsc.iterator();
        Iterator itr2 = student_name_list_time_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            while(itr2.hasNext())
            {

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------
                followup_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                followup_tr_data.setId(10);
                followup_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                followup_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                final TextView timeNameText = new TextView(this);
                timeNameText.setId(20);
                timeNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr.next().toString()));
                timeNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                timeNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                timeNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(timeNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                final TextView StudentNameText = new TextView(this);
                StudentNameText.setId(20);
                StudentNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr2.next().toString()));
                StudentNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                StudentNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                StudentNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(StudentNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------

            }

        }
    }


    //Name ascending method
    public void populateTableNameAscending()
    {
        getTimeNameSyudentAsc();
        getStudentNameStudentAsc();
        follow_up_table.removeAllViews();
        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow followup_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        followup_tr_head.setId(10);
        followup_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        followup_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView time_name_title = new TextView(this);
        time_name_title.setId(20);
        time_name_title.setText("Time");
        time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        time_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(time_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        time_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        TextView student_name_title = new TextView(this);
        student_name_title.setId(20);
        student_name_title.setText("Student Name");
        student_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        student_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(student_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        student_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableTimeDescending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------

        student_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableNameDescending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------


        follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //--------------- Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        Iterator itr = time_name_list_studname_asc.iterator();
        Iterator itr2 = student_name_studname_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            while(itr2.hasNext())
            {

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------
                followup_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                followup_tr_data.setId(10);
                followup_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                followup_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                final TextView timeNameText = new TextView(this);
                timeNameText.setId(20);
                timeNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr.next().toString()));
                timeNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                timeNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                timeNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(timeNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                final TextView StudentNameText = new TextView(this);
                StudentNameText.setId(20);
                StudentNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr2.next().toString()));
                StudentNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                StudentNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                StudentNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(StudentNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------

            }

        }
    }   



    //Name descending method
    public void populateTableNameDescending()
    {
        getTimeNameStudentDsc();
        getStudentNameStudentDsc();
        follow_up_table.removeAllViews();
        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow followup_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        followup_tr_head.setId(10);
        followup_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        followup_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView time_name_title = new TextView(this);
        time_name_title.setId(20);
        time_name_title.setText("Time");
        time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        time_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(time_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        time_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        TextView student_name_title = new TextView(this);
        student_name_title.setId(20);
        student_name_title.setText("Student Name");
        student_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        student_name_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        followup_tr_head.addView(student_name_title);// add the column to the table row here
        student_name_title.setTextSize(12);    

        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        time_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableTimeDescending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click time_name_title---------------------------------------

        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------

        student_name_title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //makeAToast("Hello!");
                populateTableNameAscending();

            }
        });
        //----------------------On click student_name_title---------------------------------------


        follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //--------------- Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        Iterator itr = time_name_list_studname_dsc.iterator();
        Iterator itr2 = student_name_list_studname_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            while(itr2.hasNext())
            {

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------
                followup_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                followup_tr_data.setId(10);
                followup_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                followup_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                final TextView timeNameText = new TextView(this);
                timeNameText.setId(20);
                timeNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr.next().toString()));
                timeNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                timeNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                timeNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(timeNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                final TextView StudentNameText = new TextView(this);
                StudentNameText.setId(20);
                StudentNameText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itr2.next().toString()));
                StudentNameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                StudentNameText.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                StudentNameText.setTextSize(10);
                followup_tr_data.addView(StudentNameText);// add the column to the table row here

                follow_up_table.addView(followup_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //----------------table body------------------------------------------

            }

        }
    }   




    //==================================================================================//  
    //=============Functions for Table View=====================================================//
    //==================================================================================//      




    //==================================================================================//  
    //=============Functions for DB=====================================================//
    //==================================================================================//  
    //=================Time name ascending=================================
    public void getTimeNameTimeAsc()
    {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        time_name_list_time_asc = db.getTimeNameTimeAsc();
        Iterator itr = time_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }

    public void getStudentNameTimeAsc()
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        student_name_list_time_asc = db.getStudentNameTimeAsc();
        Iterator itr = student_name_list_time_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }

    //=================Time name ascending=================================



    //=================Time name descending=================================
    public void getTimeNameTimeDsc()
    {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        time_name_list_time_dsc = db.getTimeNameTimeDsc();
        Iterator itr = time_name_list_time_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }

    public void getStudentNameTimeDsc()
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        student_name_list_time_dsc = db.getStudentNameTimeDsc();
        Iterator itr = student_name_list_time_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }

    //=================Time name descending=================================


    //=================Student name ascending=================================
    public void getTimeNameSyudentAsc()
    {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        time_name_list_studname_asc = db.getTimeNameSyudentAsc();
        Iterator itr = time_name_list_studname_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }

    public void getStudentNameStudentAsc()
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        student_name_studname_asc = db.getStudentNameStudentAsc();
        Iterator itr = student_name_studname_asc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }

    //=================Student name ascending=================================



    //=================Student name descending=================================
    public void getTimeNameStudentDsc()
    {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        time_name_list_studname_dsc = db.getTimeNameStudentDsc();
        Iterator itr = time_name_list_studname_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }

    public void getStudentNameStudentDsc()
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        student_name_list_studname_dsc = db.getStudentNameStudentDsc();
        Iterator itr = student_name_list_studname_dsc.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }

    //=================Student name descending=================================



    //method to insert data into local database
    public void insertData(String timeName, String time, String studentName)
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(TableActivity.this);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //db.createDataBase();
        values.put("timeName",timeName);
        values.put("time",time);
        values.put("studentName",studentName);

        db.insertValues(timeName, time, studentName);
        db.close();

    }

    //method to delete all rows
    public void deleteRows()
    {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        db.deleteAllData();
        db.close();
    }
    //==================================================================================//  
    //=============Functions for DB=====================================================//
    //==================================================================================//  

    //method to show toast message
    public void makeAToast(String str) {
        //yet to implement
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to set the color in populateTableTimeDescending(); Try to setText Color in OnClick itself. or else pass a reference to that method.

Comment: @Santhosh I had setText Color in OnClick itself but it did not work.

Comment: I wrote an answer with something which worked for me. just check out. couldn't paste the code here in comments so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
textview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACk);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the use of this? What color will be displayed?

Answer (score 3):

Another way change text color on click is:
Add resource file: 
XML file saved at res/color/button_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And set as textColor for you widget:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

For more dital look at [**google guide**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Answer (score 1):

Insure that you're trying to change text color in proper TextView and try to call setTextColor after populateTableTimeDescending();

Answer (score 0):

```
 final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Sample TextView");

    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    rl.addView(tv);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            populateTableTimeDescending();//since you are setting the color of the TextView back to same(white) again in this method, set the color of the textView after calling the method. 
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //**edited**
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the requirement of the relative layout?

Comment: No, its just for my purpose. i didn't use TableLayout. both are just containers. so, it won't matter. you use the tablelayout itself.

Comment: Didn't you wrote `tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));` in `populateTableTimeDescending();` ?? And please try to paste your full code. If not possible atleast manage to include all the related methods you have created, that you are mentioning in the code.

Comment: @kittu88: Ah, my hunch was right. you are setting the TextColor to white again in that method populateTableTimeDescending(); so do this, in every onClick(), first call the method which you want and then set the TextView color as required.

Comment: @shree202 no, some other color

Comment: @Santhosh but, firstly the textviews are independent to each method. Secondly, if it would have been possible to change the color in the called method, the color will remain different. I wanted to show a click effect to the user

Comment: I mean you are trying to set the same color `time_name_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);` in `populateTableTimeAscending()` and `populateTableTimeDescending()`check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the same color. Check it out.[image]

[image]

Please change the color first in any of the method.

--------------edit-------------

then do `textview.setColor(Color.BLUE);` before `populateTableTimeDescending();` in your `onClick();`

Comment: I know that, actually I want to supply a click effect to the textview, the color will change momentarily, secondly the text views are method specific!

Comment: you can also set the shadow effect on the textview to give a "look n feel" like click event occured, as, `textView.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color);`

Comment: @shree202 If you would have done the arrows with ascii art it would have been cool. But now the code cannot be indexed or copied.

Answer (score 0):

Here, after four digits, you can set whichever color you'd like using a hexadecimal color code:

```
time_name_title.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
```